# Jquery mobile. Reaction on slider movement

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, slider

I’m a newbie to web programming and trying to write a simple app, which works on multiple platforms. I have a slider and to do something at every movement or changing the value.

The code is:

```
<label for="slider-getankt">Getankt (l):</label>
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-getankt" value="30" min="0" max="60"  />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slider-getankt').bind ("tap", function(){
    alert('hi')
});
</script>
```

Nothing happens.
How do I react proframmatically on slider movements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the script block in `<head>` and placed it within `$( function() { "my code" });`

Hope it helps somebody.